# Client connect server c# network

Tags: c#, network-programming

```
IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] (127,0,0,0));
TcpClient con = new TcpClient ();
con.Connect(ip,5020);
byte[] dtabfr;
dtabfr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
NetworkStream strm =con.GetStream();
strm.Write(dtabfr,0,dtabfr.Length);
strm.Close();
con.Close();
```

Error IPAddress ip    Array creation must have array size or array initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 IPAddress ip = new IPAddress(new byte[]{127,0,0,0});
```

or just do

```
var ip = IpAddress.Parse("127.0.0.0");
```